# dynamic select field in ecto query

Tags: ecto, dynamicquery

I have a trouble with ecto query situation, that I Have a ORDER table with basic fields: `current_status, picked_up_at, delivered_at, returned_at`. where: `picked_up_at, delivered_at, returned_at` is Date type. and data struct i want to query back is: `%{ current_status, date }`, where date is one of the value of `[picked_up_at, delivered_at, returned_at]`

it depends on value of `current_status` if `current_status` == "picked_up" so date in result will be `picked_up_at` field and so on. the problem is i can create a dynamic query field in `Select` query

Hope you guys can help! thank you!